# How to write a XSLT for this XML?

Tags: xml, xslt, svg, xsl-fo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 14.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 43363)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="612px"
     height="792px" viewBox="0 0 612 792" enable-background="new 0 0 612 792" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Original_Text">
    <line x1="92.676" y1="500.913" x2="92.676" y2="500.262"/>
    <line x1="15.208" y1="500.913" x2="15.208" y2="500.262"/>
    <line x1="92.676" y1="500.262" x2="92.676" y2="500.913"/>
    <line x1="15.208" y1="510.329" x2="15.208" y2="509.678"/>
    <line x1="92.676" y1="500.913" x2="92.676" y2="500.262"/>
    <rect x="15.208" y="574.678" display="none" width="77.468" height="0.651"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 258.6782 28.9111)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="8.4629">Bartlet</tspan><tspan x="24.459" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="8.4629">t</tspan><tspan x="26.895" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="8.4629"> </tspan><tspan x="29.035" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="8.4629">Managemen</tspan><tspan x="76.081" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="8.4629">t</tspan><tspan x="78.601" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="8.4629"> </tspan><tspan x="80.741" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="8.4629">Services</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 522.9805 39.562)"><tspan x="0" y="0" fill="#0000FF" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Report</tspan><tspan x="21.493" y="0" fill="#0000FF" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">s</tspan><tspan x="25.382" y="0" fill="#0000FF" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="27.343" y="0" fill="#0000FF" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Home</tspan></text>

        <line fill="none" stroke="#0000FF" stroke-width="0.651" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="522.98" y1="40.213" x2="569.852" y2="40.213"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 261.2822 39.3267)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Consolidate</tspan><tspan x="37.818" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">d</tspan><tspan x="41.901" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="44.105" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Weekl</tspan><tspan x="64.001" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">y</tspan><tspan x="67.975" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="70.18" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Sales</tspan><tspan x="88.092" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="90.297" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Report</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 522.9775 49.3267)"><tspan x="0" y="0" fill="#0000FF" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Stor</tspan><tspan x="13.133" y="0" fill="#0000FF" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">e</tspan><tspan x="17.566" y="0" fill="#0000FF" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="19.527" y="0" fill="#0000FF" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Finder</tspan></text>

        <line fill="none" stroke="#0000FF" stroke-width="0.651" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="521.98" y1="49.978" x2="562.341" y2="49.978"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 282.7881 49.9775)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">P</tspan><tspan x="4.776" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">D</tspan><tspan x="10.27" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="12.475" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">    /   </tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 123.5044 60.8589)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Wee</tspan><tspan x="14.724" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">k</tspan><tspan x="18.949" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="21.153" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">1</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 190.1138 60.8589)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Wee</tspan><tspan x="14.724" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">k</tspan><tspan x="18.949" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="21.153" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">2</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 261.6782 60.8589)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Wee</tspan><tspan x="14.724" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">k</tspan><tspan x="18.949" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="21.153" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">3</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 331.377 60.8589)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Wee</tspan><tspan x="14.724" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">k</tspan><tspan x="18.949" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="21.153" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">4</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 400.3164 60.8589)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Wee</tspan><tspan x="14.724" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">k</tspan><tspan x="18.949" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="21.153" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">5</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 461.751 60.9487)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">P</tspan><tspan x="4.805" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">-</tspan><tspan x="7.404" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">T</tspan><tspan x="11.808" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">-</tspan><tspan x="14.406" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">D</tspan><tspan x="19.864" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="22.068" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Total</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 527.6309 60.8589)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Yea</tspan><tspan x="12.741" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">r</tspan><tspan x="15.699" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">-</tspan><tspan x="18.298" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">T</tspan><tspan x="22.673" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">o</tspan><tspan x="27.12" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">-</tspan><tspan x="29.72" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Dat</tspan><tspan x="40.863" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">e</tspan><tspan x="45.419" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="47.623" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Total</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 112.853 72.6265)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">$</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 148.0059 72.6265)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">%</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 184.4619 72.6265)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">$</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 218.9629 72.6265)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">%</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 255.4194 72.6265)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">$</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 289.9204 72.6265)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">%</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 326.377 72.6265)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">$</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 360.8779 72.6265)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">%</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 397.334 72.6265)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">$</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 431.835 72.6265)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">%</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 470.2461 72.6265)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">$</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 506.0508 72.6265)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">%</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 546.4092 72.6265)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">$</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 584.1689 72.6265)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">%</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1997 83.394)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Ne</tspan><tspan x="9.154" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">t</tspan><tspan x="11.716" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="13.677" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">-</tspan><tspan x="16.277" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="18.237" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">KFC</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1997 94.1616)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Ne</tspan><tspan x="9.154" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">t</tspan><tspan x="11.716" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="13.677" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">-</tspan><tspan x="16.277" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="18.237" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">A&amp;W</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1997 104.9287)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Ne</tspan><tspan x="9.154" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">t</tspan><tspan x="11.716" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="13.677" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">-</tspan><tspan x="16.277" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="18.237" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">LJS</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1924 115.6963)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Ne</tspan><tspan x="9.154" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">t</tspan><tspan x="11.716" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="13.677" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">-</tspan><tspan x="16.277" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="18.237" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">TB</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1924 126.9639)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Tota</tspan><tspan x="14.329" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">l</tspan><tspan x="16.457" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="18.661" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Net</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1851 149.2949)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Las</tspan><tspan x="11.545" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">t</tspan><tspan x="13.671" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="15.632" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Yea</tspan><tspan x="28.374" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">r</tspan><tspan x="31.252" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="33.213" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Sales</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1855 161.0625)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Increase</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.2065 171.8296)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Las</tspan><tspan x="11.545" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">t</tspan><tspan x="13.671" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="15.632" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">yea</tspan><tspan x="27.178" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">r</tspan><tspan x="29.949" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="31.91" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Nex</tspan><tspan x="44.644" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">t</tspan><tspan x="46.884" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="48.845" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Week</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.2065 193.3574)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Chicken</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1997 205.125)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Filets</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1997 215.8926)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Popcor</tspan><tspan x="22.689" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">n</tspan><tspan x="26.686" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="28.646" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Chicken</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1997 226.6602)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Crisp</tspan><tspan x="16.71" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">y</tspan><tspan x="20.828" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="22.788" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Strips</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1997 237.4272)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Special</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1924 248.1948)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Wings</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1924 257.9624)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Subtota</tspan><tspan x="24.686" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">l</tspan><tspan x="26.448" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="28.652" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Chicken</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1851 280.2935)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Shortening</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1851 291.5605)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Flour</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1851 302.3281)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Biscuits</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1851 313.0957)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Frie</tspan><tspan x="12.332" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">s</tspan><tspan x="16.278" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="18.239" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">/</tspan><tspan x="20.844" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="22.805" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Onio</tspan><tspan x="37.931" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">n</tspan><tspan x="42.329" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="44.29" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Rings</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1851 323.9385)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Potatoe</tspan><tspan x="24.686" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">s</tspan><tspan x="28.646" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="30.606" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">-</tspan><tspan x="33.206" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="35.167" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Mashed</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1851 334.6309)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Desserts</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1851 345.3979)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Drinks</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1851 357.1655)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Corn</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1851 367.4331)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Ms</tspan><tspan x="9.545" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">c</tspan><tspan x="13.663" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="15.624" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Entrees</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1846 378.2002)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Salads</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1846 388.9678)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Condiments</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1846 400.2354)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Paper</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.2012 410.9385)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">A&amp;</tspan><tspan x="9.553" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">W</tspan><tspan x="16.927" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="18.888" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Sandwiches</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1943 421.2051)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">LJ</tspan><tspan x="7.563" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">S</tspan><tspan x="12.368" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="14.329" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Product</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1938 431.4736)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">T</tspan><tspan x="4.374" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">B</tspan><tspan x="9.766" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="11.727" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Product</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.208 441.2402)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Tota</tspan><tspan x="14.329" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">l</tspan><tspan x="16.457" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="18.661" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">C.O.S</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.187 465.0713)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Hourl</tspan><tspan x="17.112" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">y</tspan><tspan x="20.829" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="22.79" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Labor</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1797 474.8389)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Mgm</tspan><tspan x="15.913" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">t</tspan><tspan x="18.225" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="20.186" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Labor</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1724 486.6064)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Tota</tspan><tspan x="14.329" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">l</tspan><tspan x="16.457" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="18.661" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Labor</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1655 507.7412)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Tota</tspan><tspan x="14.329" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">l</tspan><tspan x="16.457" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="18.661" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Controllable</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1655 530.2686)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Charg</tspan><tspan x="19.503" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">e</tspan><tspan x="24.088" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="26.048" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Count</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1729 542.0361)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Charg</tspan><tspan x="19.503" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">e</tspan><tspan x="24.088" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="26.048" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Ticke</tspan><tspan x="43.157" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">t</tspan><tspan x="45.576" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="47.537" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Average</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1553 563.5635)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Coupo</tspan><tspan x="21.102" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">n</tspan><tspan x="25.385" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="27.346" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Count</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1479 574.3311)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Coupo</tspan><tspan x="21.102" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">n</tspan><tspan x="25.385" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="27.346" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">$</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1582 595.8594)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Ticke</tspan><tspan x="17.108" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">t</tspan><tspan x="19.528" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="21.489" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Average</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1582 617.3867)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Hea</tspan><tspan x="13.136" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">d</tspan><tspan x="17.57" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="19.531" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Average</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1582 628.1543)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Piece</tspan><tspan x="17.913" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">s</tspan><tspan x="22.138" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="24.099" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Scrapped</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1514 639.4219)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Piece</tspan><tspan x="17.913" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">s</tspan><tspan x="22.138" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="24.099" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Unacc</tspan><tspan x="44.396" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">.</tspan><tspan x="46.887" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="48.848" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">For</tspan></text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1514 650.6895)" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Efficiency</text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 15.1514 671.2168)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">Cas</tspan><tspan x="12.734" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">h</tspan><tspan x="16.925" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="18.885" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">ove</tspan><tspan x="30.431" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">r</tspan><tspan x="33.202" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609"> </tspan><tspan x="35.163" y="0" font-family="'ArialMT'" font-size="7.1609">/(short)</tspan></text>
    <path stroke="#000000" d="M10,488.932"/>
</g>
<g id="Pieces_Unaccounted">
    <g id="l_x5F_u_x5F_pieces_x5F_unaccounted">
        <line id="UnaccountedFor_1_" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" x1="10" y1="640" x2="599.5" y2="640"/>
    </g>
</g>
<g id="Total_Labor">
    <g id="Double_Lines">
        <line id="Btm_Line" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" x1="11" y1="490.932" x2="600.5" y2="490.932"/>
        <line id="Top_Line" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" x1="11" y1="488.932" x2="600.5" y2="488.932"/>
    </g>
    <line id="Line_Above" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" x1="10.5" y1="477.5" x2="600" y2="477.5"/>
</g>
<g id="Total_Cos">
    <g id="Double_Line_3_">
        <line id="Btm_Line_3_" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" x1="11" y1="444.932" x2="600.5" y2="444.932"/>
        <line id="Top_Line_3_" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" x1="11" y1="442.932" x2="600.5" y2="442.932"/>
    </g>
    <line id="Line_Above_6_" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" x1="10.34" y1="433.097" x2="599.84" y2="433.097"/>
</g>
<g id="SubTotal_Chicken">
    <g id="Double_Line_2_">
        <line id="Btm_Line_1_" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" x1="7" y1="261.932" x2="596.5" y2="261.932"/>
        <line id="Top_Line_1_" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" x1="7" y1="259.932" x2="596.5" y2="259.932"/>
    </g>
    <line id="Line_Above_1_" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" x1="7" y1="250.097" x2="596.5" y2="250.097"/>
</g>
<g id="total_Net">
    <g id="Double_Line_1_">
        <line id="Btm_Line_2_" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" x1="7" y1="130.932" x2="596.5" y2="130.932"/>
        <line id="Top_Line_2_" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" x1="7" y1="128.932" x2="596.5" y2="128.932"/>
    </g>
    <line id="Line_Above_3_" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" x1="7" y1="119.097" x2="596.5" y2="119.097"/>
</g>
<g id="Header_Underline">
    <line id="Line_Above_4_" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" x1="8.34" y1="74.5" x2="597.84" y2="74.5"/>
</g>
<g id="Total_Controllable">
    <line id="Line_Above_2_" stroke="#000000" x1="7" y1="498.066" x2="600.5" y2="498.066"/>
    <line id="Line_Under" stroke="#000000" x1="7" y1="509.329" x2="600.5" y2="509.329"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

The above code is generated xml file, and i need to write a xslt transformation to get the fo file, for the PDF generation, how do I do it??

The doubt I have is, that I dont now how to represent the  tags in xslt, and also I need to represent the line, path and text in the form of xslt. how can I do this any ideas, with really get me going...

Actually I have to use a style sheet like this:

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" > 
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master margin-right="1.5cm" margin-left="1.5cm" margin-bottom="2cm" margin-top="1cm" page-width="21cm" page-height="29.7cm" master-name="first">
                    <fo:region-body margin-top="1cm"/>
                    <fo:region-before extent="1cm"/>
                    <fo:region-after extent="1.5cm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="first">
                <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
                    <fo:block line-height="14pt" font-size="10pt" text-align="end">Embedding SVG examples - Practise</fo:block>
                </fo:static-content>
                <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
                    <fo:block line-height="14pt" font-size="10pt" text-align="end">Page <fo:page-number/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:static-content>
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:block text-align="center" font-weight="bold" font-size="14pt" space-before.optimum="3pt" space-after.optimum="15pt">Embedding SVG</fo:block>
                    <fo:block space-before.optimum="3pt" space-after.optimum="20pt">
                        <fo:instream-foreign-object>
                            <svg:svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="542px" height="505px">
                                <svg:title>A less cute tiger</svg:title>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="svg/switch/g/g/path">
                                        <svg:g style="fill: #ffffff; stroke:#000000; stroke-width:0.25">
                                            <svg:path>
                                                <xsl:variable name="s">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="translate(@d,' ','')"/>
                                                </xsl:variable>
                                                <xsl:attribute name="d"><xsl:value-of select="translate($s,',',' ')"/></xsl:attribute>
                                            </svg:path>
                                        </svg:g>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="svg/switch/g/g/g/path">
                                        <svg:g style="fill: #ffffff; stroke:#000000; stroke-width:0.5; fill-rule=evenodd; clip-rule=evenodd; stroke-linejoin=round">
                                            <svg:path>
                                                <xsl:variable name="s">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="translate(@d,' ','')"/>
                                                </xsl:variable>
                                                <xsl:attribute name="d"><xsl:value-of select="translate($s,',',' ')"/></xsl:attribute>
                                            </svg:path>
                                        </svg:g>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                            </svg:svg>
                        </fo:instream-foreign-object>
                    </fo:block>
                    <fo:block><xsl:apply-templates/></fo:block>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your XSL-FO engine you can embed SVG graphics directly. Apache FOP allows to embed SVG via `fo:instream-foreign-object` or from a separate file referenced with `fo:external-graphic`.

The following sample is taken from [here](http://www.svgopen.org/2008/presentations/65-Reporting_with_XSLFO_SVG_and_Apache_FOP/index.pdf).

Inline within the XSL-FO markup in it's own namespace:

```
<fo:block>
  <fo:instream-foreign-object>
    <svg:svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
             width="8cm" height="5cm" viewBox="0 0 80 50">
      <svg:rect x="1" y="1" width="78" height="48" 
                fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.25"/>
      <svg:text x="40" y="27" font-size="5" font-family="Tahoma">
        Photo-Placeholder
      </svg:text>
    </svg:svg>
  </fo:instream-foreign-object>
</fo:block>
```

Reference to external files:

```
<fo:block space-before="15pt" text-align="center">
  <fo:external-graphic src="url('graphics.svg')" 
                       content-height="18cm" content-width="18cm"/>
</fo:block>
```

For further details see the Apache FOP [documentation](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/0.94/graphics.html#svg-pdf-graphics).

Comment: No I do not what the XSLT in the form of embedded stuff, or through external reference.

Answer (score 0):

You should check XSL-FO project. It's about XML to PDF via XSLT. Exactly your case. Lines there too.

http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/

http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/